# APIs for ADO.net entity framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, api

what are the APIs do i need to download in order to make ADO.NET Entity Framework available for my VS 2008 professional edition.

Comment: ADO.NET Entity Framework is part of the .NET 3.5 Service Pack 1 release. That plus the Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 release give you everything you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get the Entity Framework as soon as you install Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

Comment: Some Webpages suggest to install Entity Framework Tools CTP1,ADO.NET Entity Framework Beta 2.

Comment: Check the dates on those sites...SP1 should give you 1.0 which is the stable release that came after Beta 2. If you like the cutting edge...you could download VS2010 and try the beta of the next version of Entity Framework.